# Grep , uniq and sort

Tags: grep

What this expression does?

```
grep -oP "TYPE=\w+" | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: What part do you not understand after reading the manual of those 3 commands?

Comment: i need to understand "TYPE=\w+"

Comment: [ExplainShell.com is useful for this sort of question](http://www.explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep+-oP+%22TYPE%3D%5Cw%2B%22+%7C+sort+%7C+uniq+-c)

Answer (score 8):

This searches for any `TYPE=sometext` on `stdin` (`-P`is for Perl-like regex, where `\w+` is "one or more non-whitespace characters) and prints only the matching parts of the input (`-o`).

It then sorts it (required for using `uniq`), which then prints for every `TYPE=something` how often it occured (`-c`).

Comment: thank you so much for making it clear. extremely obliged